# How to move <div> using css, flexbox, js - wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox

I used a plugin and created this structures: class1   class2   class 3 [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frxjm.jpg)

```
<div class="total">
      <div class="aaa"></div>
      <div class="bbb"></div>
      <button class="ccc"></button>
</div>
```

I need to make it like this: [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzHv9.jpg) using css, flex, JS etc.
class1
class2 class3
Would you please let me know how to ?
Thak you.

Comment: Please make some attempt at solving this yourself. What have you tired? What didn't work? Questions, where a set of requirements are given with no attempt to solve the issue, tend to no be received well

Comment: It's working, I'm sorry I was looking on template page, it works well on product page, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```css
.total {
  max-width: 100%
}

.total div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

.aaa {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.ccc, .bbb {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="total">
      <div class="aaa"></div>
      <div class="bbb"></div>
      <button class="ccc"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't work... 3 divs are still in one line ..

Comment: It's working, I'm sorry I was looking on template page, it works well on product page, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the following way, I hope it works for you:

```css
.row2 {
  display: flex;
}

.aaa {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.bbb {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.ccc {
  width: 80px;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="total">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="aaa">aaa</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="bbb">bbb</div>
    <button class="ccc">ccc</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your hlep, but I created the code using plugins, so I can't write the new css. I can only edit the css... Is there any why to add div into existing code using php?

Comment: I did this, check it bro: https://codepen.io/johan-sanchez-the-reactor/pen/bGgezqy

Comment: It's working, I'm sorry I was looking on template page, it works well on product page, thanks a lot

Comment: Nice bro! Keep coding <3

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div class="total">
  <div class="aaa" style=“display:block;”></div>
  <div class="bbb"></div>
  <button class="ccc"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: What plugin did you use? Also are you using a css styles file?

Comment: It's working, I'm sorry I was looking on template page, it works well on product page, thanks a lot

Comment: The first `<div class="total">` wasn't even closed. Please make sure that you close all opened tags.